# Connect to Cloud SQL using IP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, ipv6, google-cloud-sql

I want to connect to a Google Cloud SQL instance using IP (not from another google service like appengine). To connect I'm using phpMyAdmin and MySql, both cannot connect.

**CloudSql Instance details**

- Instance type: `MySQL First Generation` tier: `D1`
- Version: `MySQL 5.5`
- Authorized network: `::/0` (everybody based on [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/diagnose-issues#viewing_logs))
- Authorized user: a user with no password and allowed from any domain (`%`)

**Connecting client specs**

- phpMyAdmin `4.6.4` (fresh install)
- MySQL Version `5.5.52-cll`

So I have an instance that can be connected from everywhere but still cannot connect.

**MySql using ssh**

`mysql --host=the:ipv6:of:the:instance --user=theusername --password`

and I get an error

`ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'the:ipv6:of:the:instance' (110)`

**PhpMyAdmin config.inc.php**

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'the:ipv6:of:the:instance';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'some secret';
```

The error here is: `#2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'the:ipv6:of:the:instance' (110) — The server is not responding.`

**Verifying ipv6**

Since I'm connecting using ipv6, I had to verify that I'm not hallucinating and I am indeed connecting from an ipv6 client.

The phpMyAdmin was run from `http://[my:own:ipv6:address]/index.php` so no doubt that I was indeed using ipv6

[**edit**] As suggested by [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40495939/245495) I ran `ping6 www.google.com` from the client and worked, also checked that the client can be accessed using its ipv6 by pinging it from another computer (from windows: `ping -6 my:own:ipv6:address`)

**References**

- [Connecting MySQL Client Using IP Addresses](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-client)
- [Using phpMyAdmin with Cloud SQL on App Engine Standard Environment](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/phpmyadmin-on-app-engine)
- [Diagnosing Issues with Cloud SQL Instances](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/diagnose-issues)

**Other things I tried**

- Another user: root, a user with password
- To another new cloud sql instance
- Checked the console [log viewer](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer), nothing interesting
- Veryfied that there is an `AAAA` for my ipv6 on the domain I am requesting from, that ip resolves and my dns works perfectly
- I am not behind a proxy

**Any** help would be greatly appreciated to either connect or at least debug what is going on. I want to clarify that I don't consider myself above novice in network-related stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the two different cases have different errors, they are clearly different issues.

**Command Line issue**

You may not have IPv6 connectivity on the host you are SSHing to - for example GCE does not. To test this try running `ping6 www.google.com`. You may also have an outbound firewall on port 3306.

**PHPMyAdmin issue**

You should be using `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']` instead of  `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']`. You will also need to set a password and possibly a username too. You should not be running Cloud SQL with no password required.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort in helping with this, its not my field and I feel a bit lost. The target is a google cloud sql instance so for sure has an ipv6 and can be accessed, there is something wrong with my conf. You were correct about the `socket/host` in my cont, I change it and now the two errors match.
I tried with/without passwords on the users for the sake of debugging only.
I edited the question with your suggestion and updated the results

Comment: I found it, it was the firewall. Actually, you found it.. Thank you very much!